# how to adapt a box to an object with a python script?

Tags: python, scripting

First I create a bouding box around an object with this script :

```
selected = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in selected:
    #ensure origin is centered on bounding box center
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='BOUNDS')
    #create a cube for the bounding box
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() 
    #our new cube is now the active object, so we can keep track of it in a variable:
    bound_box = bpy.context.active_object 
    #copy transforms
    bound_box.dimensions = obj.dimensions
    bound_box.location = obj.location
    bound_box.rotation_euler = obj.rotation_euler
```

Then I resize the box like I wish :

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1.4,1.4,3.5))
```

This is my result :

[image]

After that I want to resize only the highest face of the box so that it arrive 5 mm above the object, like this :

[image]

I already know this script to select the highest face of the bouding box :

```
object = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
object.select = True
me = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
for face in bm.faces:
    center = face.calc_center_median()
    if center.z >= 1:
        face.select_set(True)
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

I equally know how to get the highest point of the object :

```
max = -9999
for i in obj.data.vertices :
    if i.co[2] > max :
        max_ind = i.index
        max  = i.co[2]
```

But I don't know how to position the highest plan of the box 5 mm above the highest point of the object ?

Comment: If you want to use the bmesh module for this operation, you need to get the top face's vertices (you can't move faces and edges directly, but their verts; it's as simple as `face.verts`). Then translate the vertices, either by individually changing their `.co.z` value or by using `bmesh.ops.translate()`. The latter will be relative to the vertices' current locations.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to move the highest plan of the bounding box and position it correctly above the object :

```
activeob = bpy.context.selected_objects
cube = activeob[0]
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[cube.name]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(cube.data)  
ob = bpy.data.objects[cube.name]
matrix = ob.matrix_world
for v in mesh.verts:
    if v.select:
        v.co = v.co*matrix
        v.co.z += 20
        matrix_inv = matrix.inverted()
        v.co = matrix_inv*v.co
```